# appending html-rows dynamically with use of localStorage and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I created an application using jquery to have table rows be appended dynamically. The application works as follows:

Whenever a user clicks the button 'append' a row should be appended to my table. The appended row contains three columns: origin, destination and distance. The user needs to fill in an orgin, and an destination and once he or she clicks the button again, using the google-maps api, a distance should be calculated and presented in the distance column. Next a key will be set to localStorage with a key-value containing the data of each column seperated by "|" (for example: 1|4701jx|4731jd|calculated distance). Then an empty row will be generated within the table. The application also presents an message (#msg) whenever any textfield left empty. Once the page is refreshed the stored data will be converted to an array containing each value of each column for each row and will be set as content. So when the page reloads the application generates table rows with saved content.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 function htmlToAppend(var key, var arr)
 {
  var html = "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>" +
  "<td><input type='text' value='"+ arr[1] +
  "' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
  "<td><input type='text' value='"+ arr[2] +
  "' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
  "<td>"+arr[3]+"</td></tr>";
  
  return html;
 } 
  
 
 function emptyHtmlToAppend(var rowIndex)
 {
  var html = "<tr>"+
  "<td>"+rowIndex+"</td>" +
  "<td><input type='text' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
  "<td><input type='text' maxlength='6'/></td>" +
  "<td></td>"+
  "</tr>";
 
  return html; 
 }
 
 var rowIndex = 1;
 
 $("#tbl").append(emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex));
 if(!(localStorage.length==0))
 {
     for(var i = 0; i<localStorage.length;i++)
  {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
    var arr = val.split("|");
  
    $("#tbl").append(htmlToAppend(i,arr));
  
    rowIndex++;
    }
 }

 $("#btn").click(function()
 {
  rowIndex++;
  $("#msg").hide();
  
  var prevInput1 = $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+
  ") td:nth-child(2) input").val();
  var prevInput2 = $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+
  ") td:nth-child(3) input").val();
  
  if(!(prevInput1=="" || prevInput2==""))
  {
   var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService() 
   var request = 
   {
    origin:prevInput1, 
    destination:prevInput2,
    travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
   };
   
   directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
   {
    if(!(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK))
    {
     $("#msg").text("no results found!");
     rowIndex--;
    }
    else
    {
     var dist =  (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value)/1000;
      $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+") td:nth-child(4)").text(dist);
    }
   });
   
   var val = ""+(rowIndex-1)+"|"+prevInput1 +"|"+prevInput2+"|" + $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+") td:nth-child(4)").text();
   localStorage.setItem((rowIndex-1),val);
   
   $("#tbl").append(emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex));
  }
  else
  {
   $("#msg").text("no data found!");
   $("#msg").show();
   rowIndex--;
  }
  
 });
 
 $("#clear").click(function()
 {
  localStorage.clear();
 });

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>TestLocalStorage_2</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">javascript</script>
<div id="msg"></div>
<table id="tbl"></table>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="append">
<input id="clear" type="button" value="clear">
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately my code is not working. I have looked over it serveral times to see if there is anything I missed. When I start the application and I click 'append' I get no response. I have checked if I did anyhting wrong in the semantics, but to me it seems all logical. Could anyone explain to me where I went wrong?

kind regards: Tim

Comment: You have many syntax errors in the posted code.

Comment: I checked the syntax for small errors, like forgotten characters etc. But It still does not seems to work. Could anyone point me out where it went wrong. I got this code up and running before.

Comment: Oke I figured out that I can't call a function within $(element).append(). For now distances are calculated and A new row is set. But I still have to figure out some Issues with localStorage item retrieval

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use `var` statement in function signature (list of input variables).

Then, only code is allowed in a `<SCRIPT>` tag.

Finally, your code may be improved :

- use a domain (i.e encapsulate your key/data array) in localStorage because your user may have another values already stored that will ruin your app as you're reading all the keys). I get around with calling `localStorage.clear`in the code below but it removes all previous user data.
- use a specific id/class/data attribute to identify your current active row; You'll only need to switch class instead of looking for a slow nth-child (though it's working).

*** EDIT ****
Here's a working code with a "domain" localStorage. For storing your data, it must be first encoded to become a string. I'm using JSON.stringify for that.
I moved your storage update and add new line to trigger only if the response id succesful and the clear button also removes all lines.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestLocalStorage_2</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="msg"></div>
<table id="tbl"></table>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="append">
<input id="clear" type="button" value="clear">
<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';    

$(document).ready(function()
{
    function htmlToAppend(key, arr)
    {
        var html = "<tr><td>" + key + "</td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' value='"+ arr[1] +
        "' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' value='"+ arr[2] +
        "' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
        "<td>"+arr[3]+"</td></tr>";

        return html;
    } 


    function emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex)
    {
        var html = "<tr>"+
        "<td>"+rowIndex+"</td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' maxlength='6'/></td>"+
        "<td><input type='text' maxlength='6'/></td>" +
        "<td></td>"+
        "</tr>";

        return html;    
    }

    var dist, val;
    var rowIndex = 1;
    var myTravels = {}; // or [] as array if keys are indexed

    if(localStorage.getItem('myTravels')) // -------- Change here
      // -------- Decode object myTravel
      myTravels = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myTravels'));
      {
        for(var key in myTravels)
        {
          var val = myTravels[key];
          var arr = val.split("|");          
          $("#tbl").append(htmlToAppend(key, arr));
          rowIndex++;
       }
    }

    $("#tbl").append(emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex));

    $("#btn").click(function()
    {
        rowIndex++;
        $("#msg").hide();

        var prevInput1 = $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+
        ") td:nth-child(2) input").val();
        var prevInput2 = $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+
        ") td:nth-child(3) input").val();

        if(!(prevInput1 == "" || prevInput2 == ""))
        {
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService() 
            var request = 
            {
                origin:prevInput1, 
                destination:prevInput2,
                travelMode:google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status)
            {
                if(!(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK))
                {
                    $("#msg").text("no results found!");
                    $("#msg").show(); //--------- Added
                    rowIndex--;
                }
                else
                {
                    dist = (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000;
                    // Display distance result
                    $("#tbl tr:nth-child("+(rowIndex-1)+") td:nth-child(4)").text(dist);
                    // -------- Store value
                    myTravels[rowIndex-1] = (rowIndex-1)+"|"+prevInput1 +"|"+prevInput2+"|" + dist;;
                    // -------- Encode object myTravel in JSON before saving to localStorage
                    localStorage.setItem('myTravels', JSON.stringify(myTravels));
                    $("#tbl").append(emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex));
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $("#msg").text("no data found!");
            $("#msg").show();
            rowIndex--;
        }

    });

    $("#clear").click(function()
    {
        localStorage.removeItem('myTravels'); // -------- Change here
        rowIndex = 1;
        $("#tbl").empty().append(emptyHtmlToAppend(rowIndex));
    });

});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I use a what you said: domain for my local storage? The main purpose is not to remove user data on reload, It should stay there in case the user accidentely closes the browser

Comment: Well. You set up a root key to use. E.g myTravels = {key1: {town1a, town1b, distance], key2={town2a, town2b, distance, ...}, localStorage.setItem('MyTravels', mytravels) to save it and localStorage.getItem('Mytravels') to get it back

Comment: I will implement the domain storage later on. But first I face another problem and I also tried numerous ways to work around it. But it still does not seem to work: In my code I'm assembling a key that has the following ouput: origin|destination|distance. When I save the key to localStorage It only saves the origin and destination values, not the distance value. I tried to convert that data to a string type but it still not seems to work. Can anyone tell, looking at my code, why the calculated distance by google-maps is not stored?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that before. You can't store javascript objects (arrays are objects) as a string. The easiest way is to use JSON.
I modified the code accordingly and made some upgrades

Comment: Wow, now it is working perfecly! I think i'll be doing good learning JSON for now on, thanks a lot!